# Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL in Android

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, unsafe

I am loading into a `WebView` some HTML code that contains two `iframe`s. Those 2 `iframe`s will point to pages in my private folder. So basically I have:

`page.html` (in assets folder)

```
...
<body>
   <iframe src="page_1.html" />
   <iframe src="page_2.html" />
</body>
...
```

`Webview.java`:

```
String pageContent = readeFileContents("page.html", getActivity().getAssets());
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///data/data/com.mypackage/", pageContent, "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
```

Then if in my `page.html` I try to access the content of the iframes, I get this:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:////data/data/com.mypackage/page_1.html from frame with URL file:////data/data/com.mypackage/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

(I get the same error for both `page_1` and `page_2` of course.)

I'm trying this on a galaxy tab 2 Android 4.1.2

Comment: Did you got the answer for the same?